# Kafka consumer does not start from latest message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to have a Kafka Consumer which starts from the latest message in a topic.

Here is the java code:

```
private static Properties properties = new Properties();
private static KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
static
{
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers","localhost");
    properties.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    properties.setProperty("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.setProperty("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");
    properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);

    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("mytopic"));
}

@Override
public StreamHandler call() throws Exception
{
    while (true) 
    {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(200);
        Iterable<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records = consumerRecords.records("mytopic");
        for(ConsumerRecord<String, String> rec : records)
        {
            System.out.println(rec.value());
        }
    }
}
```

Although the value for *auto.offset.reset* is **latest**, but the consumer starts form messages which belong to 2 days ago and then it catches up with the latest messages.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you run this same code before with the same `group.id`? The `auto.offset.reset` parameter is only used if there is not an existing offset already stored for your consumer. So if you've run the example previously, say two days ago, and then you run it again, it will start from the last consumed position.

Use `seekToEnd()` if you would like to manually go to the end of the topic.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392174/1392894 for a slightly more thorough discussion of this.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right! I had used it two days before and I was not aware that, by latest offset it means the latest offset that a group.id has been consumed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manually control the position of your offsets you need to set enable.auto.commit = false.

If you want to position all offsets to the end of each partition then call seekToEnd()

https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seekToEnd(java.util.Collection)