# Spring Kafka - How to reset offset to latest with a group id?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am currently using Spring Integration Kafka to make real-time statistics. Though, the group name makes Kafka search all the previous values the listener didn't read.

```
@Value("${kafka.consumer.group.id}")
private String consumerGroupId;

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(getDefaultProperties());
}

public Map<String, Object> getDefaultProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);

    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId);

    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaMessageListener listener() {
    return new KafkaMessageListener();
}
```

I would like to begin to the latest offset, and not be bothered by old values. Is there a possibility to reset the offset of the group ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Because I didn't saw any example of this, I'm gonna explain how I did here.

The class of your `@KafkaListener` must implement a `ConsumerSeekAware` class, which will permit to the listener to control the offset seeking when partitions are attributed. (source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#seek )

```
public class KafkaMessageListener implements ConsumerSeekAware {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "your.topic")
    public void listen(byte[] payload) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        assignments.forEach((t, o) -> callback.seekToEnd(t.topic(), t.partition()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {


    }
}
```

Here, on a rebalance, we use the given callback to seek the last offset for all the given topics. Thanks to Artem Bilan ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756547/artem-bilan ) for guiding me to the answer.

Comment: `callback.seekToEnd()` is really equivalent to the `auto.offset.reset = latest`

Comment: You should read this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390265/what-determines-kafka-consumer-offset

Comment: You saved life of my friend, Thank you!!

Comment: The doc Link is outdated, here's the new link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/seek.html

Answer (score 6):

Another way, we can always consume lastest message without commit group offset , by specify properties value with `{"enable.auto.commit:false", "auto.offset.reset:latest"}` for KafkaListener annotation.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "example-group",
        properties = {"enable.auto.commit:false", "auto.offset.reset:latest"},
        topics = "example")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `ConsumerRebalanceListener` for the kafka consumer while you subscribing to some topics,in which you can get the lastest offset of each partition by `KafkaConsumer.endOffsets()` method, and set this to consumer by `KafkaConsumer.seek()` method ,like this:

```
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topics),
    new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            //get and set the lastest offset for each partiton
            kafkaConsumer.endOffsets(partitions) 
                .forEach((partition, offset) -> kafkaConsumer.seek(partition, offset));
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use partitionOffsets annotation to start with exact offset,for example:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "bar", topicPartitions =
    { @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1", partitions = { "0", "1" }),
      @TopicPartition(topic = "topic2", partitions = "0",
         partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "1", initialOffset = "100"))
    })public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
     }
```

Comment: Since Kafka topics usually have retention times associated this approach might fail as offset "100" might not exist (since the brokers will delete data after X days). The docs aren't too clear what happens if the offset does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

For a new consumer group that doesn't have an initial offset in kafka, you can set `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG`:

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumer-group-id");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
```

For an existing consumer group, you can:

1. Change group id to appear as new i.e. `consumer-group-id-v2`
2. Implement `ConsumerSeekAware` so you can seek to desired offset during initialization [See docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#topicpartition-initial-offset)

Comment: If you don't have an initial offset, this works. But here we want to "reset" the offset !

Comment: @Bachrc Exactly, it is just a workaround, iff you can afford to change your consumerGroupId say from `my-consumer` to '`my-consumer-v2`. It becomes a new group that doesn't have an initial offset in kafka.

Comment: Obviously, it is not always possible to do so.