# Kafka Consumer configuration - How does auto.offset.reset controls the message consumption

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand, how does the ConsumerConfig.auto.offset.reset = latest would affect the message consumption.

For example I've a consumer, sending 100 messages initially at time t1 and then my consumer is up and running at t1+30 sec, then would my consumer consume the messages published after t1+30 sec or will it consume messages published  t1 onwards?

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends.

`auto.offset.reset` only applies when there is no stored offset for the consumer group.

It applies to the following conditions:

- the first time a consumer group consumes
- if a consumer doesn't commit any offsets, the next time it is started
- if a consumer group has been expired (7 days by default with modern brokers)
- if the message the stored offset points to has been removed due to message retention policies (an attempt to read a message that has been purged triggers the application of the rule)

If a consumer commits an offset; it will start at the last committed offset the next time it is started.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I've a question on the 1st point,  if the consumer is up for the first time and ready to consume messages but the publisher/producer has already produced some messages before the consumer is ready, then would it not consume those messages produced before the consumer is ready?

Comment: If it's set to `latest`, it will not read any existing records under **any** of the conditions I described above.

Comment: With this config set to latest, we should always have the consumer deployed first and make sure it's ready and then start producing messages. If I don't want to have that dependency on the order of deploying an app, should i go for 'earliest' instead of 'latest'? If yes, this might cause processing same message more than once if we restart the consumer. So, what is your suggestion to address both these issues? Please suggest.

Comment: `earliest` will work, as long as the consumer processes at least one record after it is first started (and commits the offset) and runs at least once a week. If you only run once a month then you will have to increase the offset retention property.

Comment: with earliest, if we have to restart the consumer (because of some reason) after it processed all the messages already, then I believe it would process them again which is a duplicate work and if i don't want that, how should i design this

Comment: No; it would not; as long as the consumer commits the offsets for the records it has read. If you are using spring-kafka, the container will do it for you. If you are using the consumer directly, you must call one of the commit methods, depending on your requirements. The next time the consumer starts it will consume from the last committed offset.