# Kafka: Fetch offset is out of range for partition. How to avoid data loss?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

```
Fetcher INFO : Fetch offset .... is out of range for partition ..., resetting offset
```

Trying to understand what happens when this happens.
If offset we are trying to to read is missing (I assume because of kafka GC'ed the offet) and `auto.offset.reset = latest` do we skip over data to the latest offset?

What is the safe configuration to avoid data loss?

Comment: It depends, if the offset is out of range because it the request offset was deleted already, then you already lost data. Having the offset reset policy as latest will reset to the most recently produced record so you'll open yourself up for data loss there as well. You probably want the policy to be earliest to read from the beginning or none to force the consumer to fail so you can make your own decision on how to recover if you want to avoid data loss in this scenario

Comment: Thank you @dawsaw, this really helps. I also found a good explanation on "How does auto.offset.reset controls the message consumption" here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829112/kafka-consumer-configuration-how-does-auto-offset-reset-controls-the-message-c

Answer (score 1):

For me,  I Fixed it by adding the below line in my KafkaConsumer configurations

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```