# springboot consumer wont consume any messages

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a springboot consumer app. When I ran it the first time, it was consuming messages from the Kafka topic. But when I ran it again, it stopped consuming. In the logs I see the following message.

```
2022-08-02 00:14:08.130  INFO 96561 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-transformation-local-1, groupId=my-transformation-local] Fetch position FetchPosition{offset=17400, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}} is out of range for partition CraveVideoTestLog-0, resetting offset
2022-08-02 00:14:08.135  INFO 96561 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-transformation-local-1, groupId=my-transformation-local] Resetting offset for partition CraveVideoTestLog-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=56464, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}.
```

I understand that the consumer could not get the offset. In situations like this, the consumer will refer to auto-offset-reset property. As you can see, I have set it to `earliest`, hoping that the consumer would read from the beginning. But it does not.

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-transformation
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:localhost:9092}
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      retries: 2
      compression-type: snappy
    consumer:
      group-id: ${GROUP_ID:my-transformation}
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

In my Java class

```
    @SendTo("output-topic-here")
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${my-transformation.input.topic}", errorHandler = "myErrorHandler")
    public Message<?> process(Message<String> in, ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws Exception {
        log.info("Going to process event for key: {} offset: {} partition: {}", record.key(), record.offset(), record.partition());
    }
```

I tried out a few of things.

- I set the `auto-offset-reset` value to `none`. As expected, it threw an exception complaining about the offset.
- I created a new consumer group. I could see that the new consumer group was created from the confluent UI. But, again, the messages were not consumed.
- I read through a lot of posts. Here are a few that are very close to the issue I am facing. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010580/kafka-fetch-offset-is-out-of-range-for-partition-how-to-avoid-data-loss) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829112/kafka-consumer-configuration-how-does-auto-offset-reset-controls-the-message-c)

I feel I am missing something really silly, but could not figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out the reason for my consumer's behaviour. The topic's retention policy was set to **delete** and retention time was set to **default(1 week)**.

The reason why the consumer stopped consuming records was because the topic's retention time had elapsed. So the entire data in the topic was deleted and hence the consumer had nothing to read. When I pushed new records into the topic again, the consumer started consuming.

Answer (score 2):

The **auto.offset.reset** property will work in the following ways.

**Use Case 1:**
A consumer starts and has **auto.offset.reset=latest**, and the topic partition currently has data for offsets going from some range to other. The consumer group has committed the some offset for the topic before. Where will the consumer read from?

Ans : The offsets are already committed for this consumer group and topic partition, so the property auto.offset.reset is ignored

**Use Case 2:**
A consumer starts and has **auto.offset.reset=none**, and the topic partition currently has data for offsets going from some range to other. The consumer group has committed some offsets for the topic before. Where will the consumer read from?

Ans: auto.offset.reset=none means that the consumer will crash if the offsets it's recovering from have been deleted from Kafka.

**Use Case 3:**
A consumer has **auto.offset.reset=latest**, and the topic partition currently has data for offsets going from some range to other. The consumer group never committed offsets for the topic before. Where will the consumer read from?

Ans: Latest means that data retrievals will start from where the offsets currently end.

**Use Case 4:**
A consumer has **auto.offset.reset=earliest**, and the topic partition currently has data for offsets going from some range to other. The consumer group never committed offsets for the topic before. Where will the consumer read from?

Ans: Earliest means that data retrievals will start from beginning of the partition

**Use Case 5:**
A consumer starts and has **auto.offset.reset=earliest**, and the topic partition currently has data for offsets going from some range to other. The consumer group has committed the some offset for the topic before. Where will the consumer read from?

Ans : The offsets are already committed for this consumer group and topic partition, so the property auto.offset.reset is ignored

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't solve my case.

Comment: Post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace so we can see what you are doing wrong; it's hard to speculate otherwise.

Comment: Sorry..What do you mean by you ran it again? Are you testing your consumer application in local, if so the issue could be between your consumer app and broker connectivity, as the client not able to get the metadata info of that specific topic. For the trouble shoot per se, get the current offset (produce a record or by means of any topic viewer), set the value to auto.offset.reset=latest with a new group.id and restart your application. If everything is fine, then you may see the resetting logs to the latest offset and you can start producing events again and check the behaviour.