# Difference between Consumer level offset and Consumer group offset in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Trying to understand between Offset in Consumer and offset of Consumer group .

Below stack overflow link provides excellent understanding on Consumer group offset management .
[What determines Kafka consumer offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390265/what-determines-kafka-consumer-offset)
Now question here ,

**Scenarios:**

We have consumer (c1) in a consumer group group1 .

1. Is it offset value will be stored in consumer (c1) and group (group1) both level ? Or if consumer will be belong to any consumer group , offset will be stored in Only Consumer group level ?
2. If offset value will be stored in both level , will it be consumer level offset value will be override consumer group level offset value .

**Example**

Consumer level offset value - 5 
Consumer group level offset value - 8 
When system will be restarted from 8 ?

**Reverse:**

Consumer level offset value - 8
Consumer group level offset value - 5 
When system will be restarted from 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Kafka [consumer group management](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_1_0), if the consumer group management is enabled with `group.id` the offset will be stored in consumer group level, so that in case of re balance a new consumer can read from offset.

And if consumer group management is disabled offset is stored under consume, be default `group.id` is null if user don't provide it, So there is no chance of offset storing on both the levels

> Offset expiration semantics has slightly changed in this version. According to the new semantics, **offsets of partitions in a group will not be removed while the group is subscribed to the corresponding topic and is still active (has active consumers).** If group becomes empty all its offsets will be removed after default offset retention period (or the one set by broker) has passed (unless the group becomes active again). **Offsets associated with standalone (simple) consumers, that do not use Kafka group management, will be removed after default offset retention period** (or the one set by broker) has passed since their last commit.

[group.id:](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs)

> A unique string that identifies the consumer group this consumer belongs to. This property is required if the consumer uses either the group management functionality by using subscribe(topic) or the Kafka-based offset management 
>   strategy.

```
Type: stringDefault: nullValid Values:Importance: high
```