# Apache Kafka Consumer - terminate from console

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Apache Kafka and I am trying to consume messages from a topic. I ran the following from the console to see the messages:

```
bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

But after that I could see a consumer being created called "console-consumer-4158" and I accidentally closed the console.

How to terminate the running consumer?

Answer (score 0):

1. the process itself will be stopped after you terminate consumer.
2. as you are using old consumer API, groupId (console-consumer-4158) + information about consumed offsets are stored in zookeeper. There is no process that automatically delete not-used groups ( [see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243896/removing-a-kafka-consumer-group-in-zookeeper))

Comment: That's my question. How the consumer will get terminated or how to terminate from our end?

Comment: console consumer is a simple java process. If you close console, the process will be automatically killed