# How to delete a consumer group of a Kafka Topic from java code?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka topic T.

The user has the option to create new entries A, B, C or delete them. Upon creation of each of the entries A,B or C; I will create a consumer group with the same name for the kafka topic T.

Upon deleting the entries A,B,C; I want to delete the corresponding consumer groups without affecting the topic T by any way - but I want to achieve this from a Java module. How is that possible?

Comment: Briefly? No! see that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537950/how-to-delete-a-topic-in-apache-kafka it would undermine the skills of Kafka.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the consumer group in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is only limited Java API for this. There is a discussion in progress to add a Java AdminClient (cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-117%3A+Add+a+public+AdminClient+API+for+Kafka+admin+operations)

For Zookeeper based consumer groups (ie, old consumer from v0.8) you can have a look into the code of `ConsumerGroupCommand` -- that's Scala code, but you can still call it from Java.

For broker based consumer groups (ie, new consumer as of v0.9) you cannot delete a consumer group at all (at the moment -- it's WIP to add support for this). However, brokers delete consumer groups automatically if they are not active anymore. You can configure this "delay" via broker setting `offsets.retention.minutes` (a group is deleted if all of its committed offsets got deleted).

Comment: Is the WIP task ever complete to delete a consumer group from the broker?

Comment: Deleting consumer groups was added in AK 1.1 via https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-229%3A+DeleteGroups+API

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough points to comment but if your just looking to delete a consumer group the only way to do it is to delete the zookeeper entry `/consumers/[group_id]`. Here's a link that should point you in the right direction:
[removing a kafka consumer group in zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243896/removing-a-kafka-consumer-group-in-zookeeper)

Comment: What if you're using the new consumer which uses a group coordination protocol built into Kafka?

Comment: Only work for ZK based consumer groups -- does not work for new consumers as introduce in 0.9.