# How to delete the active consumers in apache kafka or zookeper?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to delete the consumer from zookeeper who is currently active, but observing following error:

```
docker run   --net=host   --rm <kafka docker > kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper localhost:32181  --delete --group consumer1
Delete for group consumer1 failed because its consumers are still active.
```

Is there a way in Kafka version `0.10.1.1-cp1` where we can delete the active consumers ?

Have tried to stop the active consumers but wasnt able to :

```
docker run   --net=host   --rm <kafka docker > kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper localhost:32181  --stop --group consumer1

Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: stop is not a recognized option
    at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:449)
    at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:381)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupCommandOptions.<init>(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:424)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:44)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing a kafka consumer group in zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243896/removing-a-kafka-consumer-group-in-zookeeper)

Comment: Are you sure all the consumers from this group are stopped?

Comment: @ValBonn Consumers are still active and i want to delete the consumer which are active. I tried stopping the consumers but wasn't able to. ```docker run   --net=host   --rm <kafka docker > kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper localhost:32181  --stop --group consumer1```

Comment: Your command line is about the consumer *groups*. You cannot stop consumers this way. The consumers are apps which connect to Kafka and consume topics. These consumers are part of "consumer groups". If you want to delete a group via the `kafka-consumer-groups --delete`, you have to stop the consumers which are part of this group before deleting the group.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I stop the consumers which are part of the group with command line ?

Comment: You can only stop the consumers with command line if they run on the same machine. You can already try to identify what are the consumers: `kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper localhost:32181  --describe --group consumer1  --members`

Comment: Error is seen when tried to check the consumers members ```Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: members is not a recognized option
```

Comment: You actually have to stop the consumer process, which these commands don't do... You need to find the actual consumer code, its process, then kill it there.

Comment: Killing the consumer process will be on client side, I was looking to stop the consumers from server side.